# Maximum and minimum of $f(x) = 4x^{-1} + x$

Tags: calculus

Consider $f(x) = 4x^{-1} + x$. I found the critical points $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$, which gives me the two points $(2,4)$ and $(-2,-4)$ when substituted into the main function.

Initially I thought the maximum was $(2,4)$ and the minimum was $(-2,-4)$. I've even graphed it on desmos, and it seemed right. However, it turns out that the maximum is $(-2,-4)$ and the minimum is $(2,4)$.

I don't seem to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in saying that (2,4) and (-2,-4) would be candidates for max or min. However, they are but local minimum and local maximum respectively, because the function itself grows infinitely in both directions (and when approaching  `x=0` on either side).[image]